# Hudson build error: LifecycleExecutionException Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in

Tags: maven, hudson, javac

I created a dynamic web project in eclipse for a web service with axis2. I then converted it into Maven project, I'm able to compile and generate war file in eclipse, but when i deploy it on server and try to build it with Hudson-3.0.0 it gives me following error:

> mojoFailed org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2(default-compile)
>
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project   WebServices: Compilation failure
> Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6..\lib\tools.jar
> Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
> not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).

Please Let me know what's wrong with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem, ever since I upgraded Hudson from 2.2.1 to 3.0.1.
Both JAVA_HOME environment variable and JDK in hudson configuration point to JDK and not to JRE. 
If I run mvn compile in the workspace directory of the job, everything works well.

Comment: I recreated the job, but used a freestyle job now. I'm not sure that it's because of the freestyle or just because it's a new job, but now it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the hudson cannot find java_home. 
In hudson settings java.home property is set correctly ?
Does any other java projects builds successfully ?

Comment: That sounds plausible. Perhaps the build doesn't have a particular JDK/SDK tied to it and it's falling back to the default which is actually a JRE. Furthermore, if this is a slave, you might want to allow Hudson to install the JDK for you, or do so manually.

Comment: @SajithSilva: I've already added JAVA_HOME in Hudson's System Configuration:

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_33
and yes, I'm able to build other projects

Comment: For some reason your maven cannot find java. If I were you I would try to isolate the problem. 1. Can you build the project outside jenkins (command line maven) 2. what does java -version output you. When you said you can build other projects I assume those were using maven-compiler-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Did you do what the exception said yet?

> Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
>   not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).

Sounds like you don't have Java installed.  So install it.

Comment: He does have Java installed, but it's just a JRE and not an SDK/JDK. You can't run Hudson without having Java.

Comment: @djechlin: i have java installed on my system and also I've configured Hudson as following:

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_33